# How to access an ejs variable inside a script tag present inside an ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Here I'm using **Open Meteo Climate API** to fetch climate data in order to plot a line graph in my node app. I want to render these variables into my **chart.ejs** and make them accessible inside the script tag in order to do that. I searched everywhere but didn't find any way out. Is there any way I could achieve it?

**This is my API call:**

[image: Fetching the climate data from open meteo API]

**How to get these variable inside this script tag to make the line graph?**

I want to access `var time, var temperatue_mean, var temperatue_min, var temperatue_max` Inside the script tag.

**This is the js code to plot a line graph which is inside the ejs file:**

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<% var time=time %>
<%var temperatue_mean= temperature_mean; %>
<%var temperatue_min= temperature_min; %>
<%var temperatue_max= temperature_max; %>
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var time="<%=time %>"
var temperatue_mean= "<%temperature_mean %>"
var temperatue_min= "<%temperature_min %>"
var temperatue_max= "<%=temperature_max %>"
    const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Climate Change'
        },
        xAxis: {
            title:{
                text:'Time'
            },
            categories: time
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Mean Temperature',
            data: temperature_mean
        }, {
            name: 'Min Temperature',
            data: temperature_min
        }
        , {
            name: 'Max Temperature',
            data: temperatue_max
        }]
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
```

**I tried this but failed:**

```
<% var time=time %>
<%var temperatue_mean= temperature_mean; %>
<%var temperatue_min= temperature_min; %>
<%var temperatue_max= temperature_max; %>
<script>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
var time="<%=time %>"
var temperatue_mean= "<%temperature_mean %>"
var temperatue_min= "<%temperature_min %>"
var temperatue_max= "<%=temperature_max %>"
...
</script>
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to console.log the output to see what the problem is? `res.render('chart',{ temperature_mean: 20, ... }, function (err, html) { console.log(err, html); res.send(html); })` also these lines where you redeclare variables are not needed `<%var temperatue_mean= temperature_mean; %>`

Comment: I'm able to get the results in console.log but unable to retrieve that data in the script tag.